# Is anything omitted in "The son of an air force pilot, he had a somewhat nomadic childhood." ?

Tags: ellipsis, syntax

> The son of an air force pilot, he had a somewhat nomadic childhood.

I see this sentence in the dictionary on my phone. I feel there is something missing in it. I think it could be like:

> **Being** the son of an air force pilot, he had a somewhat nomadic childhood.

Is my understanding correct? What's the grammar of the original sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The son of an air force pilot, he had a somewhat nomadic childhood.

Here's how I as a native speaker would have understood that sentence when I was six years old, before I had ever parsed a sentence in school or found out that people put labels on words and phrases.

The first phrase is actually an implicit statement.

> [He was] the son of an air force pilot.

It presents a bald existential fact (without using BE or one of its forms) that must pertain to the subject in the next part of the sentence, the person being spoken about.  The implicit **he** in the first part ("the son") and the explicit **he** in the second part refer to the same person.

There is no connective word or phrase linking the two clauses, such as **so** or **and that's why**.  Nonetheless, the first part of the sentence is understood to give the reason for the fact stated in second part of the sentence:

> [He was] the son of an air force pilot [and that is why] he had a
>   somewhat nomadic childhood.

If I thought about that sentence a bit, it would have become clear to me that causal relationships need not be explicit; we can understand the causal connection between two parts of a sentence.

> The sun high in the sky, they stopped for a drink of water.

And it would have become clear that it is not necessary to use BE or one of its forms (IS, ARE, WERE, BEING, etc) when presenting a simple fact that has bearing on another part of the sentence:

> Outdoors in the heat, they grew thirsty.
>
> The children of immigrants, they spoke two languages.

Comment: Is it the same as saying *Being the son of an air force pilot, he had a somewhat nomadic childhood.*?

Comment: It is not a particular form of the verb [BE] that is implicit, but the existential fact itself.  But BEING expresses the right underlying idea.

Comment: *The sun high in the sky, they stopped for a drink of water.* is not equal to *They are the sun high in the sky, and that's why they stopped for a drink of water.* It seems that the equation is not always working well...

Comment: @dan: What "equation"?   "The sun high in the sky" was given as an example of the causal relationship between the two parts of the sentence.

Comment: oh, i see. I take this: *[He was] the son of an air force pilot [and that is why] he had a somewhat nomadic childhood.* as the [equation] to interpret this kind of sentence.

Comment: @dan: No, you should read the answer more closely.   One aspect of your question was whether the first clause can be understood as having an implicit BE.  But then there is also the relationship of the two clauses.  The first clause can be subject-oriented, and/or causally related.

Comment: ok, then how would you interpret the sentence: *The sun high in the sky, they stopped for a drink of water.*?

Comment: *Because* the sun was high in the sky (and the day grew hot) they stopped for a drink of water.  The sun BEING high in the sky (and the day growing hot) they stopped for a drink of water.  The existential fact is causally related to the second clause.  These relationships are not explicit but implicit.

Comment: I saw the other answer said the original sentence implies that *He was a son of an air pilot. He had a somewhat nomadic childhood.* There isn't any correlation between the two clauses. So, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: There is a correlation.  Military are often transferred from military base to military base around the country, every couple of years. The children often find themselves "uprooted".

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'being' might imply the cause of a nomadic childhood. It would mean the same as:

> He had a somewhat nomadic childhood because he was the son of an air force pilot.

While the original sentence wants to imply that:

> He was a son of an air pilot. He had a somewhat nomadic childhood.

The latter part of the original sentence has a sense of implicitness as it is followed by a comma. So it's just fine the way it is.

Comment: Is *The son of an air force pilot* an appositive to *he*?

Comment: @dan, yes and that's why the trailing comma.